# How to ask a question which is similar to other downvoted and closed questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question which I would like to ask that is very similar to quite a number of other questions on SO, all of which have been closed. I believe the question is different enough that it should not be marked as a duplicate, and does not have the problems that got the other questions closed.

However, I'm afraid that if I go straight to asking the question on SO, because of the similarity, people will skim it, downvote & vote to close. While I could offer my justification after the fact, the downvotes would still result in a reputation hit and decreased viewership of the question.

What is the correct procedure for something like this? Is there some kind of 'ask the mods' feature where I can get moderator approval for a question first? Should I ask whether the question is appropriate here using the tag [question-quality]? Is there somewhere to pre-emptively post my justification so I don't get penalized by an initial flood of downvotes?

Comment: What were the close reasons used for those other questions? You may need to consider whether your question is on-topic. Some specific examples of those questions and your imagined question might help

Comment: I think you're trying to establish topicality.  What was the question you were going to ask?

Comment: I have created a separate question for details relating the my specific question for SO here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389346/are-questions-about-null-sufficiently-different-from-questions-about-nullptr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you believe that other questions are close but inappropriate, you can reference the other questions in your question and state why you believe they do not answer what you're asking.

Link to them, and add a blurb about why they're different and not relevant. This would be what you would do after the fact to react to a "bad dupe close" anyways, so doing it preemptively is OK.

Just try to make the "defense" unobtrusive. You don't want it detracting or muddying the question

---

Note though, make sure that they in fact do not answer your question. Even if another answer only broadly answers your question (instead of giving specific advice), it may still be an appropriate closure reason. It can't be expected that every question will get a tailored answer.

Comment: On top of this, I would add only one thing: *use a different title*. Worst thing you can do is take the time to compose a really good question... And then post it under a title that looks like the one used on 100 lousy closed questions.