# Are questions about NULL sufficiently different from questions about nullptr?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Many of the comments on [How to ask a question which is similar to other downvoted and closed questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389343/how-to-ask-a-question-which-is-similar-to-other-downvoted-and-closed-questions) asked for details re: the specific question I was asking, but since that question has already been answered in a generic fashion, I felt it best to create a separate question.

The question I want to ask on SO is:

> Ignoring user-defined operator overloads, are there any cases where `if (!x)` would behave differently from `if (x == nullptr)`
>
> e.g. Are there any types in the standard library for which `!x` would behave differently from `x == nullptr`

A quick google search returns many similar questions already on SO, many of which have been closed. to name a few:

- [Condition checking: if(x==0) vs. if(!x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038226/condition-checking-ifx-0-vs-ifx)
- [Checking for NULL pointer in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/checking-for-null-pointer-in-c-c)
- [C/C++ `!a` vs `a==0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801111/c-c-a-vs-a-0)
- [Do you prefer "if (var)" or "if (var != 0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404838/do-you-prefer-if-var-or-if-var-0)

I believe my question to be different from the existing questions for the following reasons:

- `nullptr` vs `0`/`NULL`

  - there is the potential for a different sequence of type conversions. I don't know enough about implicit conversions to figure out whether this could indeed change behaviour though.
  - `x == 0` (and `x == NULL` when NULL is not defined as nullptr) is not supported by some of the standard library types such as `std::shared_ptr`, but every one I checked supported `x == nullptr` and `x != nullptr`
- I'm not interested in the obvious case of when a user defines operator overloads such that `!((bool)x)` and `x == nullptr` are different.
- I'm not asking for personal preferences, I'm interested in whether there are any objective differences between the two choices

Comment: Off-topic, but `std::optional<T*>` is an answer to your question.  Given `std::optional<T*> x{nullptr};`, `!x` returns `false`, while `x == nullptr` returns `true`.

Comment: "Is my similar question OK to post?" [checks the language, sees it's c++] Suicide is never the right choice, sir.